# Accumulation set

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to solve this topology exercise but I think I am not doing it right.

> $T$ is the topology over $\mathbf{N}$ such formed by $\emptyset$ and $E_n=\{n+k: k \in \mathbf{N}\}$. Find out the accumulation set of $A=\{4,13,28,37\}$.

What I have done is: Find the closed set:
$$C_t=\{\emptyset, \mathbf{N}, \{1\}, \{1,2\}, \cdots,\{ 1,2,...,n-1\}\}.$$

$$\{4\}'=\{1,2,3,4\}\setminus \{4\}=\{1,2,3\};$$

$$\{13\}'=\{1,2,...,13\}\setminus \{13\}=\{1,2,...,12\};$$

etc

So
$$\{4,13,28,37\}=\{37\}'\setminus \{4,13,18\}=\{1,2,3,5,...,12,14,15,16,17,19,...,35,36\}.
$$

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If $x<37$, then any neighborhood of $x$ contains $37$. Therefore, all those points are accumulation points of $A$. If $x\geq 37$, then the neighborhood $E_x$ of $x$ doesn't contain points of $A$ different from $x$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a hard time following the work you've done so far, but you have the right answer.

A point will be an accumulation point of a set in this topology if and only if it is less than some element of the set.

If the point is less than some element of the set, then every open set containing that point will also contain the element of the set that is greater than the point.

If the point is a limit point, then there has to be an open set containing the point which intersects the original set somewhere other than the set. This says precisely that the original set has a greater element than the point.

Comment: First of all thank you for answering the question.
So, correct me if I am saying it wrong, the accumulation set of a certain point, x,  in the set A will be all the natural numbers except the point x itself. So, gathering all the acummulation sets together, A'=N\A.
Am I correct?

Comment: We associate accumulation points to a subset of a topological space. So we can speak of the accumulation points of the set $\{x\}$, which would just be $\{1, 2, \ldots, x - 1\}$.

Comment: It seems like you're a bit confused about the definitions, so I would make sure to get clear on those. An accumulation point $y$ of a set $A$ is a point such that any open set containing $y$ also contains a point of $A  - \{y\}$.

Comment: So, to answer your question $A' = \{x \in \mathbb{N} : \exists a \in A, x < a\}$. If we set $m = \max A$, then $A' = \{x \in \mathbb{N} : x < m\}$. If $A$ is unbounded, then $A' = \mathbb{N}$. Try to prove these statements.

Comment: All right, yes, I am quite confusing with it but now you've cleared my mind (I hope). So, first of all my candidates would be N \ A. Then I would check one by one (imagining I could do that) all the points in N\A, making sure that, if they are in an open set (an element of T), that open set also contain at least one more point of A.
So...A'={E1,...,E28}.

Comment: All right, I am going to read carefully your answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: Your first comment isn't right. You have to check all the points of $\mathbb{N}$. For each point, you have to check all the open sets containing that point and see whether they all contain another point of the original set. That's how you find the set of all limit points. If you want to prove $x$ is a limit point, then your proof will start: let $U$ be an open set containing $x$. If you want to show that $x$ is not a limit point, then your proof just amounts to finding an open set containing $x$ but not any other points of the original set.